# bootstrap 4 inline form position of the input boxes

Tags: forms, input, position, inline, bootstrap-4

I am new in bootstrap in general but try to understand it. I have a log in form as you see int he below picture. I managed to change the input boxes width but I could not manage to move both of the text boxes close to "remember me" check box,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeO1y.png)

basically I want to make the place of the textboxes as the below image ( I did it in windows paint to show! ).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bek7t.png)

Here is the body codes that I used :

```
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Test</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ">
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="test1.html">Services</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="test2.html">Contact</a>
       </li>
     </ul>

     <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
       <li class="nav-item">

         <form class="form-inline">
           <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Name</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control-sm col-2 mb-0 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="Username">

           <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Username</label>
           <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-0 mb-sm-0">
             <input type="password" class="form-control-sm col-6  mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Password">
           </div>

           <div class="form-check mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
             <label class="form-check-label">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Remember me
             </label>
           </div>

           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
         </form>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </nav>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can take some of the demo examples from Bootstrap 4's [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-controls) and use it with some of you own CSS to get your desired outcome.

This comes directly from their documentation, with some modifications to fit your use case:

```
        <form class="form-inline">
            <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputUsername">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormInputUsername" placeholder="Username">

            <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroupPassword">Password</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>

            <div class="form-check mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Then with a simple CSS rule, you can specify the width of your input elements:

```
.form-control {
   max-width: 100px !important;
}
```

Note the `!important` syntax. You should generally try to avoid using it, but in this case, it helps us override bootstraps styling.

Finally, you can see the working project [here](https://www.codeply.com/go/s16ebU5ICa).